# Post directly to twitter and youtube

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, social-networking, web

I am thinking of adding a feature to my website that allows me to write a post or add a video on my site and also post it to my twitter and/or youtube accounts with the click of a button.  Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?  I am not looking for code, just some links to documentation on how this is done.

Thanks.

Comment: [Twitter Api](https://dev.twitter.com/) - [YouTube Api](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. You have to connect with twitter and youtube, and you do it by using their API (Aplication Programming Interface). You register in their developers site and get a secret API key (kind of a password to allow you to use the API). Then, you just call their functions.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/

Youtube API: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html

On these pages you will find code examples, libraries etc. which should be sufficient for you.